# How to print wmi-object to file

Tags: powershell

I want to get info of apps and prrint them to a txt file.

```
$List = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object vendor -EQ "myVendor" | Select-Object Name, Version, Description | Format-List -Property Name, Version

$Output = 
    @"
    File created $((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))

    $($List)
"@
$Output | Out-File -FilePath "my/output/path"
```

The code above gives wrong results

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData
```

How do I print out the list to a text file?

Comment: Change `$($List)` to `$($List |Out-String)`

Answer (score 0):

`Format-*` cmdlets are used for **display purposes only**. You can capture that output using a pipe to `Out-String`, but that would not store the information in a usable manner if you later want to process the data further.
I would imaging you would be much better of if you store it in a CSV file you can open in Excel.

Also, `Get-WmiObject` is obsolete now and you should use `Get-CimInstance` wherever possible instead.

Try

```
$date    = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
$outFile = Join-Path -Path 'X:\your\output\path' -ChildPath $date
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Product | 
    Where-Object {$_.vendor -eq "myVendor"} | 
    Select-Object Name, Version, Description | 
    Export-Csv -Path $outFile -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```